# Does Pascal support passing parameters to functions?

Tags: pascal, freepascal

I'm new to Pascal and I am trying to write a simple program, but an having trouble passing values between functions. This is a small piece of what I have:

```
program numberConverter;

const
    maxValue = 4999;
    minValue = 1;

var num: integer;

function convertNumeral(number: integer):string;
var j: integer;
begin
if ((number < minValue) OR (number > maxValue)) then
    begin
    writeln(number);
    writeln('The number you enter must be between 1 and 4999. Please try again:');
    read(j);
    convertNumeral := convertNumeral(j);
    end
else 
 if (number >= 1000) then
convertNumeral := 'M' + convertNumeral(number -1000)
{more code here, left it out for space}
end;

begin
    writeln;
    writeln('Enter an integer between 1 and 4999 to be converted:');
    read(num);
    writeln;
    writeln(num);
    writeln(convertNumeral(num));
end.
```

My problem is that the value from the writeln(converNumeral(num)), mainly 'num', does not get passed to the convertNumeral function and was wondering if Pascal even does this. I figure its because I haven't declared number to be a variable, but when I do I get a compile error that it can't complete the second if statement. Thanks for your time.

Comment: can't see from this code, nothing to do with question though. PS test for 1 to 4999 outside of the function,doing it inside and then asking for another if it's not is very very very bad. Functions should do one thing.

Comment: @Tony This is what I ended up doing, creating an auxiliary method to test, solved the problem.

Comment: Makes sense breaking a piece of code that does too many things up into single purpose functions often uncovers bugs and weaknesses in an implementation.  Make it a habit, it will stand you in good stead. If there's stuuf that can be optimised by inlining, the compiler will do that for you. Always go for comprehensibility first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, values definitely get passed to functions. I promise that `num` really does get passed to `convertNumeral`. Within that function, `number` acquires whatever value resides in `num`. Perhaps there's a problem with how you're observing the behavior of your program.

Changes you make to `number`, if any, will not be reflected in `num`. The parameter was passed *by value*, so `number` stores a *copy* of the value stored in `num`; they're two distinct variables. You can use `var` to pass parameters by reference, if that's what you want.

Each recursive call to `convertNumeral` gets a *new* instance of `number`, so changes made to `number`, if any, will not appear once the function returns to the caller. Each call gets its own versions of `number` and `j`.

Comment: I edited my submission. I still can't figure out whats wrong. When I print out the value for number, I get zero.

Comment: Your additional information doesn't change the answer to your question: Pascal supports passing parameters to functions. The problem you're having is evidently not related to your question. I invite you to post a new question where you ask what's *really* wrong with your program. Please try to make it of general interest, though, or else it could be closed as "too localized." Nobody else will care about your specific program, so try to figure out what broad topic you're having trouble with (such as, maybe, whether you understand how values are *returned*, or how recursion works).